# Design Productivity Gap in ICs and Internet of things

Tags: iot

The complexity of Integrated Circuits is increasing exponentially with time which in turn make the number of available transistors to grow fast within a chip. This increase in number of transistors in an IC is way more than the productive design need. The situation raised due this problem is a well-known design productivity gap.Will  IoT and Mobile devices significantly decrease this design productivity gap?

Comment: Hi, did the posted answer help you? In that case, would you mind accepting it as it shows other interested person that this is a quality answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The advent of mobile devices, and embedded devices in general, has changed our industry and the way we manufacture them to be able to:

- Keep costs low.
- Maintain a low power dissipation.
- Miniaturize electronic components.
- Keep peripherals on-chip to reduce power consumption.
- Improve performances at the same cost.

A [commonly adopted projection](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/internet/9051590/50-billion-devices-online-by-2020.html) states that we'll have 50 billion connected devices by 2020. To respond to this demand, production lines, manufacturing processes and CPU architectures have changed over the years to respond to the market needs, and limit [design productivity gaps (DPG)](http://cordis.europa.eu/pub/ist/docs/ka4/pdesign_gap.pdf). One of the commonly-adopted solution to limit the DPG is to raise the level of abstraction in the design process to lower the gap between higher abstraction level and low-level implementations.

Also, the manufacturing process has evolved, look today at how the same manufacturing lines that were used to produce embedded devices are now themselves benefiting from the rise of the Internet of things to improve their productivity through [Industry 4.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_4.0).

You take the number of transistors as an example of a limiting factor in terms of productivity, but I don't think this is the main one for consumer electronic devices. The design of the board, the mold for the manufacture, the use of especially expensive materials can be much more limiting factors, and there is even a risk in some cases that the manufacturer will go out of business if its manufacturing process and supply chain are not ready.

In the mobile world we need horse power to enable new use-cases and improve user-experience, whereas in the IoT the situation is somewhat different, as we have different types of devices, thus having different requirements. A simple light bulb will likely require less horse power, and be better at power saving than a home automation gateway would be. In this context, the number of transistor is not as relevant as the fineness of engraving, energy dissipation, [power consumption](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2015/01/29/iot-s-impact-on-global-power-consumption-comes-down-to-standby), [security features](https://www.microchip.com/pressreleasepage/microchip-releases-industry-first-security-solution-amazon-web-services-cloud), and memory cost-optimizations.